Forma práctica y elegante de desempaquetado en python
Mi duda es la siguiente, me encuentro realizando un curso de Python y al momento de estar viendo el bucle for me encuentro testeando con una lista y con la función enumerate (Que por lo que entiendo lo que hace es: obtiene el índice y el valor de cada elemento).
En el curso se nos desafía a desempaquetar de manera elegante la lista con esta función enumerate, he aquí la lista:
numeros = [33,25,19,40]

Y primeramente lo había realizado de esta forma:
for num in enumerate(numeros):
    print(f"Indice: {num[0]} Valor: {num[1]}")

Tengo entendido que sí yo hago esto:
for num in enumerate(numeros):
    print(num)

Eso imprimiría:
(0,33) (1,25) (2,19) (3,40)

Luego la forma "elegante" y "práctica" que se sugiere en el curso es la siguiente:
for num, i in enumerate(numeros):
    print(f"El índice es {num} y el valor es {i}")

Lo que entendí que hace, investigando es: Para cada elemento de i quiero obtener el índice y el valor y almacenarlos en i y num. Quiere decir que voy almacenar el índice en num y el valor en i.
¿Por qué sería la forma más elegante y práctica de hacerlo? ¿Es por temas de rendimiento?
Muchas gracias de antemano.

la función enumerate() retorna una tupla que contiene un contador (desde start, cuyo valor por defecto es 0) y los valores obtenidos al iterar sobre iterable.  https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/functions.html#enumerate

Todos los lenguajes tienen sus cosas, y Python no iba a ser la excepción.
Usar de forma adecuada las técnicas que te da Python se le conoce como Código Pythonico o Pythonic Way. Ejemplos:
>>> # Intercambiar valores de 2 variables:
>>> a = 3
>>> b = 5
>>> a, b = b, a
>>> print(a, b)
5 3

>>> # Desempacar 2 listas en una:
>>> a = [3, 4]
>>> b = [6, 7]
>>> print([*a, *b])
[3, 4, 6, 7]

>>> # Eliminar todas las vocales de una frase
>>> frase = 'esta es una frase'
>>> print(''.join([x for x in frase if x not in 'aeiou']))
st s n frs

Presta especial atención al primero de los ejemplos, en el "intercambio de valores".
En realidad no se está haciendo un intercambio directo. Lo que pasa es a la derecha de la expresión hay una tupla aunque no tenga paréntesis, con los valores invertidos, y esta se desempaca en las variables de la izquierda.
Eso es prácticamente lo mismo que ocurre en tu caso.
>>> numeros = [33,25,19,40]
>>> enumerate(numeros)
<enumerate object at 0x00000262A24EDCB0>
>>> list(enumerate(numeros))
[(0, 33), (1, 25), (2, 19), (3, 40)]
>>> 
>>> en_obj = enumerate(numeros) # <-- Asignado a una variable
>>> elem = next(en_obj)
>>> elem
(0, 33)
>>> elem = next(en_obj)
>>> i, num = elem
>>> print(i, num)
1 25

El for de Python no solo puede recorrer estructuras como listas, tuplas y demás; también puede recorrer otros tipos como iteradores, generadores y por supuesto, objetos enumerate.
Finalmente, para que un código sea pythonico, también debe ser descriptivo. Entonces si enumerate() genera un objeto de tuplas [(idx1, val1), (idx2, val2)...] entonces las variables a las que se asignan esos elementos deben tener los nombres adecuados (i para el índice, num para el valor).
El código quedará:
for i, num in enumerate(numeros):
    print(f"El índice es {i} y el valor es {num}")

